# Documents List 3.0 changes feed API calls seem to fail ~5% of the time

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I keep hitting this error a low though non negligible percentage of the time (  low single digits in my testing ).

I am positive it isn't my code since I was able to repro this with a test case of just the same API call to check the changes feed without any changes to the data set used for my account.

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceException</code><internalReason>An unknown error has occurred.</internalReason></error></errors>
```

How does one go about debugging this issue given that there is no further detail in the error message ?

Even though it happens ~5% of the time, it is high enough that the failure is noticeable.
I see very similar behavior with drive.changes.list(), which again seems to fail at a comparable rate.

Comment: Is there any possibility for you provide a sample request body for the erroneous requests?

Comment: This is a sample request from our application, with authorization deleted. ( If this is essential to debugging, I can figure out how to provide this to you, though for obvious reasons a public forum isn't appropriate ).

url=https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/changes?&expand-acl=false&max-results=192&showroot=true&start-index=5203257&include-profile-info=true
code=500  request_headers={'Authorization': [DELETED], 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Gdata-Version': '3.0', 'Host': u'docs.google.com', 'Connection': 'close'}

Comment: response_headers={'Connection': 'close', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Server': 'GSE', 'Date': 'Thu, 09 May 2013 12:36:11 GMT', 'Expires': 'Thu, 09 May 2013 12:36:11 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.google.gdata.error+xml', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block'}
response=<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceException</code><internalReason>An unknown error has occurred.</internalReason></error></errors>